# Combine Series of If Statements into one Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Right now I have a series of if statements, each one testing if the window is scrolled past a certain point, and if it is, the background is changed. Since each if statement is very similar, I'm wondering if I can combine all the if statements into one. Since I have over a hundred images, with this method I'm currently using, I would have to make one if statement for each image.

A sample of my code is below. The only things that change you'll notice is the scrolltop()/2 > **_** and MAH00046%2028.jpg.

```
    if ($(this).scrollTop()/2 > 2800) {
    $('body').css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(    "images/chapter_background_images/MAH00046%20028.jpg")'
    });
}

if ($(this).scrollTop()/2 > 2900) {
    $('body').css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(    "images/chapter_background_images/MAH00046%20029.jpg")'
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any pattern in your if statements? For example, is every successive if statement incremented by 100 after the ">" symbol. If yes, it can be done. If the statements have no conceivable pattern, a SWITCH statement may help

Comment: each is increased by 100 and the file name increases by 1

Answer (score 3):

This will work best:

```
var imageBase = 'images/chapter_background_images/MAH00046%200';            
var scrollTopHalf = $(this).scrollTop() / 2;
if(scrollTopHalf < 2900 || scrollTopHalf > 3900)
{           
    var image = imageBase + (Math.floor(scrollTopHalf / 100)).toString() + '.jpg';

    $('body').css({
        backgroundImage: 'url("' + image + '")'
    });
}
```

My other approach was largely inefficient.

Comment: Actually, your answer is partly correct. Your calculation is wrong on the image number.

Comment: oh well, I don't bother with that. It shoudl be the other guy's job to understand the answr before using it. But I don't mind this is a place to help others so i'm still upvoting you.

Comment: I'm sad to say this haha, but these days, you are more likely to get your answer accepted if the OP can more or less copy and paste your code into his project.

Comment: So this appears to work except for images MAH00046%2001 - MAH00046%2009 (the first 9 images). Is there a modification I could make. Also, would it be possible to exclude images MAH00046%2029 - MAH00046%2039 (essentially skip over them and go right from MAH00046%2028-MAH00046%2040. Otherwise it's fantastic!!

Comment: I'm not sure why the first 9 images don't work for you. The Math.floor function should take the lowest number so `Math.floor(199/100)` should be 1 or `Math.floor(259/100)` should be 2 for instance. Also, I updated my answer to reflect your skipping the range 29-39.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using if statements, use the result of the calculation to create the link to the picture since the name of the pictures are sequential numbers.

```
var inc = 100;
var imgUrl = 'images/chapter_background_images/MAH00046%';
var url = imgUrl.concat((Math.floor(scrollTop()/2)/inc)*inc).toString());
```

I am using 100 here but you can change this value for the value of each increment between your pictures.

[javascript floor method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp)

[javascript concatenate method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp)

[Javascript tostring method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)

Comment: If you're going to link to documentation, I would recommend that you link to the Mozilla Developer Network(MDN). For instance, the floor method is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation using a for loop and assuming increments of 100 with a base of 2800 (and incrementing each jpg filename's number successfully by 1

```
function myFunction() {
var counter = //number of if statements
for (i = 28; i <= i + counter; i++) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()/2 > 100*i) {
        $('body').css({backgroundImage: 'url("images/chapter_background_images/MAH00046%200"' + i + '".jpg")'});
    }
}
```